# How to make width and height of a rectangle updates after resize in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to contain the rectangles within the image and wrote the following code. It does not work after resize because the width and height of the active object doesn't seem to update after resize.

This is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yxchng/0hL2khro/191/

```
canvas.on("object:moving", function(opt) {
    activeObject = canvas.getActiveObject()
  if (activeObject.left < 0) {
    activeObject.left = 0;
  }
  if (activeObject.top < 0) {
    activeObject.top = 0;
  }
  if (activeObject.left + activeObject.width > 1000) {
    activeObject.left = 1000 - activeObject.width;
  }
  if (activeObject.top + activeObject.height > 1000) {
    activeObject.top = 1000 - activeObject.height;
  }
  activeObject.setCoords();
});
```

Is there a better way to contain objects within image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you consider only scaling *(not skewing)*;

Updated values will be

```
height = object.height * object.scaleY;
width = object.width * object.scaleX;
```

For fabricjs V 2.x

Use [getScaledHeight](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#getScaledHeight) and [getScaledWidth](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#getScaledWidth) which returns height and width of object bounding box counting transformations respectively.

Comment: I found out the solution which is to use getScaledWidth() and getScaledHeight()

Comment: @user136266 added that, in 1.x that method was not there, and I didn't aware of that as well. Thanks ;)